# How to handle video calls at the same time on agoraIO with flutter webRTC

Tags: flutter, webrtc, agora.io, videocall

I am building an app using agoraIO on a flutter webrtc app ,the app is based on video call between 2 random players. 
I would like to know if agoraIO can handle up to 1000 calls at he same time? and if I'll need to configure a server in order to optimize the calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agora Video SDK can handle unlimited calls at the same time with one million users in a channel. You don't need to configure a server yourself. Here is the documentation about the Agora Video SDK capacity: https://docs.agora.io/en/faqs/capacity.

Comment: thank you for the clarification.What's best to use for the database between mongodb and firebase  if the video call will be saved? in a long term use